# con.Open() fails exception Transactions with IsolationLevel Snapshot cannot be promoted

Tags: c#, sql-server

The following code is working when the application "use" is "low", the insert is happening.

As soon as I am having high use, I'm getting the error

> Transactions with IsolationLevel Snapshot cannot be promoted

when I try to open the connection.
The exception is happening on the line "`cn.Open()`";

I have tried to set the database with `snapshot_isolation_state` with 0 or with 1,
or `is_read_commited_snapshot_on` with 0 or 1.... and I even have tried to use a transaction on the C# code... but it made no difference.

I do not care about transaction in this case, I just want to make inserts (no updates)....

**How can I fix this?**

My code:

```
var connectionString = @"data source=XXXX\SQL2005;initial catalog=pw_LogDBStack;user id=XXXX;password=XXXX;";
string query = "INSERT INTO LogEntry (DateTime, CallerMethod, Stack, Query) VALUES ( @DateTime, @CallerMethod, @Stack, @Query)";
//SqlTransaction transaction = null;
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    cn.Open();
    //transaction = cn.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
    //using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn, transaction))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTime", DateTime.Now);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CallerMethod", callerMethod);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stack", stackStr);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Query", c.Command.ToTraceString());
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    //transaction.Commit();
    cn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Are you using a TransactionScope in any of the calling code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix this by adding the property to the connection string `Enlist=false;`

https://www.connectionstrings.com/all-sql-server-connection-string-keywords/

Comment: This would suggest that the thread calling the code already has an ambient transaction. This is normally done with a TransactionScope class somewhere higher in the call stack. By turning Enlistment off you will be disconnecting your code from the ambient transaction meaning they will commit or rollback separately.

Comment: @MartinBrown thanks for the aditional information, I didn't know the explanation of the problem.